# Android (Java): How to import and use two classes with the same name from different libraries?

Tags: java, android, oop

I am wondering how I can use two classes with the same name (DateTime) from two different libraries. I am using two libraries, each with the following purpose:

1. `org.joda.time.DateTime`: Used to convert a DateTime date from a Gregorian calendar to the Islamic Hijri calendar.
2. `hirondelle.date4j.DateTime`: Required in a Calendar library to get the date of a calendar's cell.

However, when I execute the below import statements, I get an error on my import of `hirondelle.date4j.DateTime` import, stating that `org.joda.time.DateTime` is already defined in a single-type import.

Comment: You have to fully-qualify at least one of them. That is, import `org.joda.time.DateTime` and then refer to the other one in code as `hirondelle.date4j.DateTime` (no import). (Or vice versa; or import neither and fully-qualify both)

Comment: Why is a Java question tagged as C# and .NET, but not Java? It is not clear what language you are even asking for.

Comment: @Christopher Fixed the tags.

Answer (score 0):

@AndyTurner was correct, all I had to do was to fully qualify at least one of the usages of the libraries, like shown below:

```
hirondelle.date4j.DateTime dateTime = this.datetimeList.get(position);
```